# insert multiple rows in a table without inserting duplicates rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to merge a table that the data comes from 2 differents databases.
I operated as described below:

1 – I have done a dump of the source database table and I get the following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `t_vaccination` VALUES     (242,NULL,NULL,53,1,'20030528','0','W5770-2',0,'DTP - REVAXIS','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23'),
(243,NULL,NULL,53,1,'20130525','0','',1,'DTP - ','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23'),
(1830,NULL,NULL,50,1,'20080502','3','',0,'DTP - REVAXIS','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23'),
(1831,NULL,NULL,50,1,'20130501','4','',1,'DTP - ','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23'),
(1832,NULL,NULL,50,1,'20080502','3','',0,'PAPILLOMAVIRUS - Gardasil','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23')
```

the structure of the t_vaccination table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_vaccination` (
`nIdVaccination` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nIdVaccin` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nIdVacProtocole` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nIdPatient` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nIdUtilisateur` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`sDateInjection` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nNumInjection` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sNumLot` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nRappel` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sLibelle` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`sAction` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A 20080101000000',
`sDH_REPLIC` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`nIdVaccination`),
INDEX `NDX_t_vaccination_nIdUtilisateur` (`nIdUtilisateur`),
INDEX `NDX_t_vaccination_nIdVaccin` (`nIdVaccin`),
INDEX `NDX_t_vaccination_nIdVacProtocole` (`nIdVacProtocole`),
INDEX `NDX_t_vaccination_nIdPatient` (`nIdPatient`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_vaccination_nIdUtilisateur_utilisateur` FOREIGN KEY (`nIdUtilisateur`) REFERENCES `t_utilisateur` (`nIdUtilisateur`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_vaccination_nIdVaccin_vaccin` FOREIGN KEY (`nIdVaccin`) REFERENCES `t_vaccin` (`nIdVaccin`)
)
```

2 - I would like to insert all the rows in the t_vaccination table of the final database without inserting the duplicates rows. the new query run by inserting one row:

```
INSERT INTO t_vaccination (nIdVaccination, nIdVaccin, nIdVacProtocole, nIdPatient, nIdUtilisateur, sDateInjection, nNumInjection, sNumLot, nRappel, sLibelle, sAction, sDH_REPLIC) 
SELECT 251,41,4,53,1,'20030528','0','W5770-2',0,'DTP - REVAXIS','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23' FROM t_vaccination  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nIdVaccin, nIdVacProtocole, nIdPatient, nIdUtilisateur FROM t_vaccination WHERE nIdVaccin = 41 and nIdVacProtocole = 4 and nIdPatient = 53 and nIdUtilisateur =1 ) LIMIT 1
```

3 - Is it possible to insert rows by group by using insert where not exists because the attempts that i have done failed. here is an example of an an insert that failed:

```
INSERT INTO t_vaccination (nIdVaccination, nIdVaccin, nIdVacProtocole, nIdPatient, nIdUtilisateur, sDateInjection, nNumInjection, sNumLot, nRappel, sLibelle, sAction, sDH_REPLIC) 
SELECT 251,41,4,53,1,'20030528','0','W5770-2',0,'DTP - REVAXIS','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23' FROM t_vaccination  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nIdVaccin, nIdVacProtocole, nIdPatient, nIdUtilisateur FROM t_vaccination WHERE nIdVaccin = 41 and nIdVacProtocole = 4 and nIdPatient = 53 and nIdUtilisateur =1 ) LIMIT 1,
SELECT 243,NULL,NULL,53,1,'20130525','0','',1,'DTP - ','A 20130521170623','2013-05-21 17:06:23' FROM t_vaccination  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nIdVaccin, nIdVacProtocole, nIdPatient, nIdUtilisateur FROM t_vaccination WHERE nIdVaccin = NULL and nIdVacProtocole = NULL and nIdPatient = 53 and nIdUtilisateur =1 ) LIMIT 1
```

I hope for your help.

Regards

Motti

Comment: In reply to your question, that's what i suggest you indeed : insert avery rows of every sources on a temp table and execute the query i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way to do what you want is to remove Unique keys/indexes and remove dupes or create a temporary table without those keys. Let's assume you create a temp_t_vaccination table and import all your rows in, you'll then just have to do :

```
INSERT INTO t_vaccination (field1, field2 ...) SELECT DISTINCT field1, fields2 ... FROM temp_vaccination
```

ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html?ff=nopfpls